# Power series of the form $r \bmod q$

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, integer-partitions

I am trying exercises of Apostol Introduction to analytic number theory and I am struck on this problem of chapter partitions on page 14.

[image]

I am struck in part (b) as I have no idea on how to deal with the problem as  I can put x=x times ${\alpha}^h$  and then product in h=1 to 4 but how to prove that there will be powers of $  \alpha $  along with I's.

Can you please help proving it?

Comment: Can you show that if $S(x)$ is a power series of type $r$ mod $q$ and $\alpha^q=1$ then
$$S(\alpha x)=\alpha^r S(x)?$$

Comment: What is confusing you after @JyrkiLahtonen's comment?

Comment: Adding to @JyrkiLahtonen's point, $\prod_{n=1}^\infty(1-x^n\alpha^{nh})=\prod_{n=1}^\infty(1-(x\alpha^h)^n)=\varphi(x\alpha^h)$.